# Replacement for Heroku Scheduler

Tags: ruby, heroku, rake

Heroku's Scheduler is great. For tasks running daily, hourly or at 10 minute intervals I think it's excellent and simple.

I have a (very fast running) process I want to run every 10 *seconds*. I have it set up as a rake task, how should I efficiently and simply set this up on the Heroku platform while minimising my dyno usage?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks to Petteri it looks as though a long running Cron analogue on a worker dyno is my current best offer - something like https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork could do the grunt work. This does required 1 hour of dyno per hour, and as I'll be doing under 1s of processing every 10s this feels like I'm pushing up my costs. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe these articles give hints even though they are for Java and Python:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes-java-quartz-rabbitmq

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python